# Equality of norm $||L_{xy}|| = ||L_x \cdot L_y||$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Banach algebra. We consider, for every $x \in \mathcal{A}$, the operator $L_x: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$, with $L_x(y)=xy$.

Is it true that $||L_{xy}|| = ||L_x \cdot L_y || \leq ||L_x|| \cdot ||L_y||$ ?

I try to show it through the definition of the operator norm but I can't find a way to do it.

Any help / advice would be grateful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, you have for all $x,y,z\in \mathcal{A}$ $$ L_{xy}(z) = xyz = L_x (yz) = L_x(L_y(z))= (L_x \circ L_y)(z). $$ Thus, we have $L_{xy}= L_x \circ L_y$ and in particular the norms coincide.

Comment: You can probably write this as an answer

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Fisrt of all thanks. But does this imply that $ ||L_x \circ L_y|| = ||L_x \cdot L_y|| \leq ||L_x|| \cdot ||L_y||$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of $L_x \cdot L_y$? I am not sure why you write $\Vert L_x \circ L_y \Vert \leq \Vert L_x \Vert \cdot \Vert L_y \Vert$ as it does not appear in your question above (it is true though). You asked whether $\Vert L_{xy} \Vert = \Vert L_x \circ L_y \Vert$ and this is true as we already have $L_x \circ L_y= L_{xy}$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes, you are right. I edited my post. I forgot to type the last inequality.

Comment: The last inequality follows from the fact that $\Vert L_x (z) \Vert \leq \Vert L_x \Vert \cdot \Vert z \Vert $ for all $z\in \mathcal{A}$. In particular we have $$ \Vert L_x \circ L_y(z) \Vert \leq \Vert L_x \Vert \cdot \Vert L_y(z) \Vert \leq \Vert L_x \Vert \cdot \Vert L_y \Vert \cdot \Vert z \Vert, $$ which implies the desired inequality.